JDA Permissions
Defaults on my Discord server can't seem to use the commands where no permissions are needed for.
jda.awaitReady();
jda.upsertCommand("commandone", "This is command 1").setDefaultPermissions(DefaultMemberPermissions.ENABLED).queue();
jda.upsertCommand("commandtwo", "This is command 2").setDefaultPermissions(DefaultMemberPermissions.DISABLED).queue();

When trying this, both commands are accessible by admins, but not defaults.

The users themselves also need permissions to use commands at all, only then do command permissions come into play

First off, you should confirm your bot has the applications.commands OAuth2 Scope.
Secondly, reading the Javadocs for CommandCreateAction#setDefaultPermission states:

Sets the Permissions that a user must have in a specific channel to be able to use this command.
By default, everyone can use this command (DefaultMemberPermissions.ENABLED). Additionally, a command can be disabled for everyone but admins via DefaultMemberPermissions.DISABLED.

Considering this, your commands should work, however your servers permissions may be different. Please refer to DefaultMemberPermissions#enabledFor.
